# How to render an aspx page from a php wordpress server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wordpress, jquery, .net-4.0

I would like to have a page on our wordpress server to render an aspx page from a .net server that we have.  Is there a good way to handle this using jquery or some other php library?

I need to do this, because aspx is able to pull data from sql server and I want our web designer to properly present this data using wordpress server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .NET server is not part of the same domain as the WordPress server, your best approach would be to use an iframe instead

```
<iframe src="http://url/to/.net/server.aspx">   
</iframe
```

jQuery may also help provided both, the .NET server and the WordPress server are in the same domain.

You could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('#result').load('http://google.com');
});
```

And simply have a div in your wordpress server with id `result`, as in:

```
<div id="result" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to render the apsx page in a Wordpress page?  You also might define a shortcode in wordpress.  This should handle embedding the content server side (could use optimization, caching):

```
# shortcode  [embedcontent href="http://www.yoursite.com/page.aspx"]
function embedcontent($atts, $content = null) {
    if ( isset( $atts['href'] ) ) {
        return file_get_contents( $atts['href'] );
    }
    return '';
}

add_shortcode("embedcontent", "embedcontent");
```

Otherwise, js does have some restrictions accessing content cross-domains.